# Copy screenshot to Google Drive Document

Tags: macos, copy-paste, image-capture

This question is related to this one : [Mac (OS X 10.9.2) no longer saving screen shots](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131805/mac-os-x-10-9-2-no-longer-saving-screen-shots?newreg=0506d9c3d3fe4d4186dcd1f6fd24d103)

If I use only <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd> it works as expected, a new image is created on my desktop. If I only want to copy it to the clipboard in order to paste it later  into Photoshop or a Google Drive Document : I hear the sound but nothing append when I paste it (using <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>) . I'm using Sierra 10.12, I'm new on macOS so that's maybe a stupid thing, the options "copy to clipboard" is checked in the system pref :

[image]

Any Idea how to solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

What key combo did you use for capture to clipboard? I just tried it and it worked fine. I'm running Sierra too. I used control-shift-command-3 as my keys and then pasted into Notes. All went as expected. I had same setting in system pref keyboard as you showed. Also make sure that wherever you are pasting it accepts image files.