# Command + Shift + 4 not saving image to clipboard

Tags: macos, screen-capture, copy-paste

I saw that Command + Shift + 4 gets a regular selection for a save of your screen. When I press the shortcut, I get the rectangular selection, and when I select, I here the camera shutter noise, but then the image is not saved to my clipboard.

When I cmd+v, no image gets pasted, the thing in my clipboard is just what I had previously saved to it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> saves a file to the desktop, not to the clipboard.

Use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> to save to the clipboard.

Take a look at this comment I wrote a few years back for the full list of keyboard shortcuts related to screenshots:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/204387/60161

Comment: Is this a recent change? Because I remember myself using Command+Shift+4 until recently to capture to clipboard..(Probably its a false memory, but i got surpriced)

Comment: @anandhu no, been this way as long as I can remember.  Even my related answer I linked above was posted back in 2015 :)

Answer (score 1):

i had this issue when i moved from the touchbar mac to the m1 without touchbar. it used to be easy to select the option or destinations with the touchbar. but without, i couldnt use `command` + `shift` + `4` to send it to clipboard, it will always save to Desktop.

To change this, go to `System Settings` > `Keyboard` > `Keyboard Shortcuts` > `Screenshots`, and double click the modifier row to change the input key combinations.

hope this helps

[image: screenshot taken by keyboard shortcut]